# How can i using onRefresh and onLoadMore shoutem ui toolkit

Tags: react-native, shoutem

I am trying to install shoutem ui to my project. In one component I used `listview` from shoutem ui! But I only can display item. I can't handler `onRefresh` and `onLoadMore`?

Can anyone help me?

Here is listview:

```js
<ListView
          data={groupedData}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
          loading={this.state.refreshing}
          onLoadMore ={this.loadMoreData}
          onRefresh={this.getNewData}
        />
```

I have 2 functions for getnew, data and loadmore. They can work with normal listview.

Comment: ops i forgot .bind(this) my funtion then it not work! Now it still working!

Comment: So, now it's all working?

Comment: @Tommz no sir! Spinner when refresh still work and show! But loadmore i never seen show spinner like extension in new.shoutem.com

Comment: I think you should check how the loading should be handled here: https://github.com/shoutem/extensions/blob/master/shoutem-books/app/screens/MyBooksScreen.js#L108

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the problem here exactly. It would be useful if you could include the code of your entire screen.

The `onRefresh` callback will be called when the user performs a pull down to refresh action on the list view. `onLoadMore` will be called when the user scrolls to the end of the list. Both of those functions should be used to fetch the data, but the list will only display the data that it receives through the `data` prop.

If the problem is with the spinner remaining visible after the data has been fetched, you can control the visibility of the spinner through the `loading` prop of the `ListView`. The spinner will remain visible until you reset the `loading` prop.

So the flow should be as follows:

1. Trigger a network request in onRefresh/onLoadMore
2. When the data is fetched from the server

   - render the list by passing it the new data through the `data` prop
   - reset the `loading` prop to `false` after the network request has finished or failed